# IdentityServer4 - How to create a new endpoint that can be used to query persisted grant table

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, controller, url-routing, identityserver4

Need to query Persisted grant tabel to get subjectId of the user.
Created a new controller UserInfo in the Identity server project but not able to call from postman

**UserInfoController**

```
[SecurityHeaders]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class UserInfoController : Controller
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public UserInfoController(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: UserInfo
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.PersistentGrant.ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

**I'm useing endpoint routing in the startup file**

Comment: what error do you get? and where?

Comment: Did you try the IdentityServer built in "/connect/userinfo" endpoint? It should return the sub claim. https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/userinfo.html

Comment: I need a new endpoint that is not part of the discovery document.